# ReactiveNetwork.observeNetworkConnectivity

Tags: android, reactivex, unsubscribe

I am using ReactiveNetwork to observe my wifi. I added a callback that when the wifi gets disconnected, an alert dialog pops up. However, the dialog gets pop up when wifi is turned off while the app is not shown (home). I want to unsubscribe but I can't find the correct way to do the corresponding unsubscribe for this method. How do I unsubscribe?

```
ReactiveNetwork.observeNetworkConnectivity(context)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .filter(ConnectivityPredicate.hasType(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI))
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new Consumer<Connectivity>() {
                    @Override 
                    public void accept(final Connectivity connectivity) {
                        if(connectivity.isAvailable()) {
                            callback.onWifiConnected();
                        }
                        else {
                            callback.onWifiDisconnected();
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Comment: observeNetworkConnectivity should return something that implements Subscriber interface that has an unsubscribe method.. use it.

Comment: How do you do that specifically or can you point me to a good reference for this? I'm new to reactive.

Comment: nevermind, I found the example. Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35419062/how-to-stop-and-resume-observable-interval-emiting-ticks