# Pause and Resume rxJava Timer Android

Tags: java, android

I have implemented a timer using RxJava.

```
rx.Subscription subscription = rx.Observable.interval(1000, 1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).distinct()
                    .cache().doOnNext(new Action1<Long>() {
                        @Override
                        public void call(Long aLong) {
                           timer.setText(String.valueOf(aLong)); )
                    .subscribe();
```

I'd like to know :

1) How do I pause this timer? I used subscription.unsubscribe(); and it paused, but I do not know if it's a good idea.

2) How could I resume the timer? Let's say I paused it, so how could I continue the timer from where it has stopped?

Comment: Why are you using an Observable when multiple ways of doing Timers are built in already?

Comment: Just the need of learning ReactiveX paradigm.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can pause the timer stream after starting it. What you can do instead is use your `Subscription subscription` and call `subscription.unsubscribe()` to stop the timer. Then, when you need to restart the timer, start a new timer and add the old time to the new emissions:

```
Observable.interval(1000, 1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .map(aLong -> aLong + offset) // where offset was where you last stopped
            ...
```

A solution close to the one I described can be found here: [How to stop and resume Observable.interval emiting ticks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35419062/how-to-stop-and-resume-observable-interval-emiting-ticks)